# Animation complete listener with popupwindow

Tags: android, animation, listener, popupwindow

I have a popupwindow that is using a

> PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle()

to show a scale in/out animation for create/dismiss .Animation is working fine. I want to know when the scale in animation is complete , but I can't find a way ...

Is there a way to set a listener for the animations listed in animation style.

I guess if I make any of the following idea work , I can achieve it

- create an animation style programmatically, so that I can register listeners for the involved animations.
- instead of **PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle()** I can set animation directly to Popupwindow , something like **Popup.setAnimation.
- I can get a reference to the animations of the Popupwindow.

I tried everything I can, to find a solution but to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: If I didn't understand wrongly, you are asking if you can know when the animation is completed.

Comment: This is what I did:  The Animation was created by me using xml and there is this `android:duration` where you set the duration of your animation. To know when the animation end, I make use of the duration that you had made and set Timer right after `PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(animation)`.